# Prevent mobile context menu for chessboard.js

Tags: jquery, contextmenu, chessboard.js

Using chessboardjs.com.
Pressing a piece brings up the context menu.
[image]

**Need to prevent this context menu appearing.**

I tried this code:

```
$('.square-55d63').contextmenu(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
return false;
});
```

It does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `$(document).on("contextmenu", ".square-55d63", function(e) {...`

Comment: Thanks so much. Kudos for the suggestion. $(document).on("contextmenu", ".square-55d63",  did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JS / jQuery only you the thing is to bind it to the document/window.
Or wrap that element in your custom element. So you can block `contextmenu`

Jquery example

```js
$(window).contextmenu(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

JS example

```js
document.oncontextmenu = function(e){
 var evt = new Object({keyCode:93});
 stopEvent(e);
}
function stopEvent(event){
 if(event.preventDefault != undefined)
  event.preventDefault();
 if(event.stopPropagation != undefined)
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```